# uploading empty file goes to edit instead of new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently noticed that on my form, if I try to upload an empty file the page will get redirected to edit instead of create. If I try to upload the file with some text in it, the form will direct to create. I couldn't find any indication that this would happen as I create my object every time (it's never persisted). Is there an explanation behind this?

The code looks something like this:

```
//controller
def upload
    @new_cool_file = CoolFile.new
end  

//form in upload.html.erb
<%= form_for @new_cool_file, html: {role: "form"} do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :file %>
        <%= f.file_field :file %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Which action redirects the user to edit? what does its code look like?

Comment: Can you give us the submitted request from the form for both the erroneous and a successful request?

Answer (score 0):

I think you do some wrong in the rails routes.rb file , can you please see tutorial about file upload.
https://richonrails.com/articles/allowing-file-uploads-with-carrierwave
http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads